# if f(n) = o(g(n)), does g(n) + f(n)=Θ(g(n))?

Tags: algorithm, theory

If I have managed to prove that `f(n) = o(g(n))` (small o), it seems reasonably enough that the sum of the two functions `f(n) + g(n)` should be tightly bound by the "bigger" function `g(n)`.

I am however, having a little trouble proving it.

Comment: The equation doesn't make sense. f(n) is an actual function, while g(n) is a complexity function. You can't "sum" them together, they're of incompatible type.

Comment: @LieRyan There's nothing inherently incompatible about `f` and `g`. You wouldn't normally see them added together if you were discussing the asymptotic time complexity of algorithms, but that's not the only thing `o()` is used for.

Comment: @LieRyan I Think it's a perfectly sound equation, eg. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) or [some MIT lecture notes](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) for a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following reasoning shows the 'tight bound' in the sense of asymptotic identity (Theta):

```
    f = o(g)
<=> lim_n->oo ( f(n)/g(n) ) = 0
 => lim_n->oo ( (f(n)+g(n))/g(n) )
  = lim_n->oo ( f(n)/g(n) ) + lim_n->oo ( g(n)/g(n) )
  =           0             +            1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 f(n) = o(g(n)) means that |f(n)|<|C*g(n)|
+
 g(n) = Θ(g(n)) means that |C1*g(n)|<=|g(n)|<=|C2*g(n)|
-------------------------------------------------------
 f(n)+g(n) = Θ(g(n))+o(g(n))=Θ(g(n)) because |C1*g(n)|<=|g(n)+f(n)|<|(C+C2)*g(n)|
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy.

If `f(n) = o(g(n))`, then strictly we have `k` that makes `|f(n)| < 0.5 * |g(n)|` when `n > k` (according to the definition of little-O).

Thus `0.5 * |g(n)| < |f(n) + g(n)| < 1.5 * |g(n)| = Θ(g(n))` for `n > k`.

QED.

If `f(n)` and `g(n)` are all positive definite, then you do not need the strong small-o condition. However, when they're not, then the strong condition is needed because otherwise `f(n)` may cancel `g(n)` totally. (e.g. `f(n) = -g(n)`)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have only proven that `f+g` is bounded by a constant-factor multiple of `g` from above ( so `f+g = O(g)` [Big-O]) - to conclude asymptotic equivalence you have to argue the same from below. The reasoning you gave applies to `f = O(g), f != o(g)` too and does not exploit the stronger condition for Litte-O.

Comment: @collapsar Yes, you're right. I only did one half of that. Edited my answer.